# Cannot boot Ubuntu 12.04 from SSD

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, ssd

I cannot boot from my SSD with a fresh in stall of 12.04 LTS. I tried to boot from the flash drive and copy the grub file to the proper location on the SSD and reboot.. no luck.

There is another post out there that recommended running grub-install on the SSD once it has booted - some of the users in this thread could boot with the USB install disk. Since i cannot boot from the SSD, I cannot run grub-install. Is there any ways around this?

Answer (score 1):

First, boot into your BIOS with F10, or whatever your key is. (In my case, it's F10)

Then, go into the 'Boot' option, and make sure your SSD is on the boot list.

If not, add it to the first boot option.

If it is in the Boot order, put it **BEFORE** the OS. If you put it after, you will only be able to **read** the SSD in the OS, not boot off it.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Did this work??

Comment: I looked at the BIOS and checked the boot order. I can set the boot order and location ie, USB, CD, SATA Cards, etc but I dont have finer control over the boot sequence; I'm using a Proliant server i guess that is the problem.

So when the BIOS hits the SSD it just hangs, no purple screen, nothing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the ISO file in windMD5sum. Check these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows)

Comment: Did that. Im using a MAC so I verify the sha1 with openssl every time then follow the guide here....http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: Hmm... try putting in a LiveCD. What does it do?

Comment: I can boot from a live disk. When i do, the SSD will show up as mounted external storage. In the terminal, i cannot change or update grub even as root.

I installed the OS on a regular HD which seems to work just fine for some reason. I then imaged that disk with dd. Now, I'm dd-ing it back to the ssd. Maybe success will follow?

Comment: Maybe. If this doesn't work, try re-mounting the SSD. It might work; the mac might of not mounted it properly. Did you do `auto-mount`?

Comment: The dd thing didnt work. Im dead in the water.

Comment: Oh, no. Have you tried booting the SSD in another PC?

Comment: There is something going on with the bootloader at install time. Others have similar problems so im doubtful about getting it to boot anywhere at the moment. Ill try another OS on it, make sure the firmware is updated (again) and go from there...i guess

Comment: Ok. I did hear that there was a bug with the download link when you installed it. Have you tried an older/newer version of Ubuntu on the same SSD? Like 12.10 or something.